# Access is Denied Error while running batch file to copy files

Tags: batch-file

```
echo off
copy "\\192.168.7.10\C$\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ABC\Detail.csv" \\192.168.7.20\C$\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Book\"     
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" set /A a=1
if "%errorlevel%"=="1"  set /A a=0 
if %a%==1 Echo copy successful  
if %a%==0 Echo Failed to copy 
 PAUSE
Exit
```

Please suggest why this error persists while i am running batch script

Comment: This file copy between two machines. Source machine is able to ping the destination machine(which is server) but also unable to copy from source to destination. In between showing "Access is Denied.."

Answer (score 1):

This error persists either because you have no permission to read from `"\\192.168.7.10\C$\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ABC\Detail.csv"` or because you have no permission to write to `\\192.168.7.20\C$\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Book\`.

Also you have a superfluous double quote at the end of `\\192.168.7.20\C$\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Book\`.

Comment: a superfluous at the end or (more probably) a missing one at the start of the path...

Comment: @Stephan yes, of course it is either one or the other.  I decided to go with superfluous because there are no spaces in the 2nd path, so quotes are not necessary.

Comment: right, not necessary here, but it's better to stick to the safe side and *always* enclose paths/filenames with quotes.

Comment: Hi. I am able to ping the server , where i want to copy the file but also unable to copy the file there .

Comment: Hi  Stephan , I tried with and without  double quotes .. So please suggest any way to find out the causes . I want to use servers credentials like username and password  of server (at destination) where i want to copy the file . Suggest the solution

Comment: @ Mike Nakis , i am awaiting for your response .I consider it as user credential issue because i don't have access to the server (where i have to move the file ) but instead of that i have user login access.

Comment: You are trying to move a file from an admin share to an admin share.  You need to have not only access to both servers but actually administrator access.

Comment: I would recommend that you begin by drive-mapping the two paths.  If you can't drive-map them, you will never be able to copy anything.

Comment: Thanks @ Mike Nakis . I got your suggestion .